# Selector :required no funciona en Input CSS

Tags: html, css, formularios

tengo el siguiente formulario.

```css
.form-control{
    border-radius: 100vw;
    margin-bottom: .75rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding: 0.375rem 1.5rem !important;
    position: relative;
}
.form-control:required::after{
    content: '*';
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #417A5F;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="modalForm">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                 <h5>Form</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" required>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                    <select name="gender" class="form-control" id="gender" required>
                        <option value="Null" selected hidden>Gender</option>
                        <option value="M">Male</option>
                        <option value="F">Female</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth" required>
                    <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                    <input type="tel" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code">
                    <input type="text" name="street" id="street" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" required>
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City" required>
                    <select name="state" class="form-control" id="state" required>
                        <option value="Null" selected hidden>State</option>
                    </select>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y actualmente tengo el problema con el selector :required, pues al parecer solo reconoce un input de todos los que también estan en required. ¿Que podria estar pasando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el `pseudo-element` de `:before` y `:after` solo funcionan en etiquetas contendoras, y dado que input no puede contener otros elementos, no lo tiene. Es por ello que solo te aparece en el `select`, ya que este sí contiene `:after` dado que  puede contener otros elementos.

Puedes verificar que quitando el `:after` aplica para todos los elementos.

```css
.form-control{
    border-radius: 100vw;
    margin-bottom: .75rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding: 0.375rem 1.5rem !important;
    position: relative;
}
.form-control:required{
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="modalForm">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                 <h5>Form</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" required>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                    <select name="gender" class="form-control" id="gender" required>
                        <option value="Null" selected hidden>Gender</option>
                        <option value="M">Male</option>
                        <option value="F">Female</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth" required>
                    <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                    <input type="tel" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code">
                    <input type="text" name="street" id="street" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" required>
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City" required>
                    <select name="state" class="form-control" id="state" required>
                        <option value="Null" selected hidden>State</option>
                    </select>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Según lo que veo en el código. el OP quizo agregar `*` en todos los campos que son requeridos, pero solo funciona con uno de ellos.

Comment: no creo que sea eso, ya que si eliminas el color del elemento after y aplicas un color diferente a cada form-control, ves que el elemento que tiene el * es el date.

Comment: si eso es lo que quiere pero esto no lo puede lograr con ::after o ::before por lo explicado en la respuesta, tiene que obligatoriamente usar dos elementos y un poco de javascript si quiere agregar el *

Comment: En este caso tendría que usar javascript, para validar qué campos son requeridos y a ellos darle una clase específica para el `*`, ya no vendría ser necesario el `::before` o `::after`.

Comment: es un poco confuso ya que `::before` y `::after` no agregan un elemento después del en este caso input, estos selectores agregan un elemento dentro del input cosa que no es posible por esta razón no se le ve como el espera

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de Sr1871 es válida pero algunos tipos de inputs se saltan la norma. Aquí una lista de como afecta

```css
input{
    border-radius: 100vw;
    margin-bottom: .75rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding: 0.375rem 1.5rem !important;
    position: relative;
}
input::after{
    content: '*';
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #417A5F;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="modalForm">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                 <h5>Form</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"> 
                    <label>Button</label>
                    <input type="button"><br>
                    <label>checkbox</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="ok"><br>
                    <label>color</label>
                    <input type="color"><br>
                    <label>date</label>
                    <input type="date"><br>
                    <label>datetime-local</label>
                    <input type="datetime-local"><br>
                    <label>email</label>
                    <input type="email"><br>
                    <label>file</label>
                    <input type="file"><br> 
                    <label>image</label>
                    <input type="image"><br>
                    <label>month</label>
                    <input type="month"><br>
                    <label>number</label>
                    <input type="number"><br>
                    <label>password</label>
                    <input type="password"><br>
                    <label>radio</label>
                    <input type="radio"><br>
                    <label>range</label>
                    <input type="range"><br>
                    <label>reset</label>
                    <input type="reset"><br>
                    <label>search</label>
                    <input type="search"><br>
                    <label>submit</label>
                    <input type="submit"><br>
                    <label>tel</label>
                    <input type="tel"><br>
                    <label>text</label>
                    <input type="text"><br>
                    <label>time</label>
                    <input type="time"><br>
                    <label>url</label>
                    <input type="url"><br>
                    <label>week</label>
                    <input type="week"><br>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

En estos casos se suele usar elementos extra y CSS. No hace falta nada de js.
Por ejemplo podriamos usar un div extra y el selector :has

```css
.form-control {
    border-radius: 100vw;
    margin-bottom: .75rem;
    text-decoration: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding: 0.375rem 1.5rem !important;
   
} 
.form-field {
 position: relative;
}
.form-field:has(input[required])::after  {  
   content: '*';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 1em;
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="modalForm">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                 <h5>Form</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"> 
                   <div class="form-field">
                     <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" class="form-control"   required> 
                   </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Este ejemplo no sería valido todavía para Firefox pues no tiene el soporte habilitado por defector para estos selectores .

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

Los pseudo selectores `:before` y `:after` solo funcionan con etiquetas que cuentan con inicio y cierre, por ejemplo, `<span></span>`, no funcionan con etiquetas que no tienen cierre, por ejemplo `<input stype="text">`

Por lo que lo mejor sería plantear una solución basada en javascript, como estas usando Bootstrap supongo que también estás usando jQuery, entonces puedes probar algo como esto.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        // Obtenemos todos los inputs con Placeholder
        let inputs = jQuery( 'input[required]' );

        // Actualizamos el Placeholder
        inputs.each(function(){
            let placeholder = jQuery(this).attr( 'placeholder' );
            jQuery(this).attr( 'placeholder', '* ' + placeholder );
        });

    });
```

Quedando algo como esto

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

        // Obtenemos todos los inputs con Placeholder
        let inputs = jQuery( 'input[required]' );

        // Actualizamos el Placeholder
        inputs.each(function(){
            let placeholder = jQuery(this).attr( 'placeholder' );
            jQuery(this).attr( 'placeholder', '* ' + placeholder );
        });

    });
```

```css
.form-control{
border-radius: 100vw;
margin-bottom: .75rem;
text-decoration: none;
appearance: none;
padding: 0.375rem 1.5rem !important;
position: relative;
}
.form-control:required::after{
content: '*';
font-size: 1.5rem;
color: #417A5F;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <div id="modalForm">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                     <h5>Form</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" required>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-input" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
                        <select name="gender" class="form-control" id="gender" required>
                            <option value="Null" selected hidden>Gender</option>
                            <option value="M">Male</option>
                            <option value="F">Female</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="date" name="dob" id="dob" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth" required>
                        <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                        <input type="tel" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code">
                        <input type="text" name="street" id="street" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" required>
                        <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control" placeholder="City" required>
                        <select name="state" class="form-control" id="state" required>
                            <option value="Null" selected hidden>State</option>
                        </select>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Sin embargo lo que recomiendo es que no te compliques la vida, simplemente agrega un label con tu texto sin necesidad de recurrir a otros metodos.